# FindBy with Select Element

Tags: java, select, selenium

I'm trying to run the following code but i keep getting a null pointer on the Select element ...

Here is the example of my code I use:

```
  @FindBy(id="ddCompany")
    WebElement Select;

  public void Test(){

    driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtdfUsername")).sendKeys("dimitri");
        Select dropdown = new Select(Select);
        dropdown.getOptions().get(1).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("igtxtdfPassword")).sendKeys("dimitri");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
    driver.quit();
```

We can't use the Driver.findElement function so we have to find a way to work arround with the Find By .. I putted a sout after the dropdown but it just gave me Null.

Comment: Why can't you use the findElement function to find the Select?

Comment: your (select) having null value so you are getting exception..

Comment: initialize the Select webelement before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem today,

Problem was i needed to use the pagefactory and because i was using a Webdriver page object where i define my Webdrivers (all 3 different browsers) i needed to place the Pagefactory just before my function now he doesn't return a null pointer anymore because now the function gets the right Driver to use and it all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use xpath to locate the select element if you don't have className, id or name. you're getting an exception because the constructor for select is expecting a not null WebElement

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java

Answer (score 2):

First of all select class has constructor like :

```
Select(WebElement element)
```

So if you do like below , it should work :

```
@FindBy(id="ddCompany")
private WebElement Select;
Select dropdown = new Select(Select);
dropdown.getOptions().get(1).click();
```

Make sure your ID for find element is correct.

You can check more about [Select mechanism here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find Element for:

```
  WebElement select;
```

That select variable is not initialized, so that you will get the NullPointerException at the following line:

```
  Select dropdown = new Select(Select);
```

So findElement for select variable, then only you will get the drop down options. Otherwise it will throw an exception.